# Array sort by date and month only (ignore year)

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have following festival array:

```
id = 1, Start_date = 2011-11-01 , End_date = 2016-12-31

[[1, 2011-11-01 , 2016-12-31],
[2, 2011-11-28 , 2016-12-31],
[3, 2011-10-01 , 2015-12-31],
[4, 2011-11-28 , 2021-12-31],
[5, 2010-11-15 , 2016-12-31],
[6, 2011-07-01 , 2017-12-31],
[7, 2012-02-01 , 2013-02-19],
[8, 2011-03-21 , 2015-04-30],
[9, 2012-03-01 , 2016-03-20]]
```

I need to sort this by `start_date` start from current date but ignore year here (use only month and day).

Actually these are festival's start dates and end dates. I need to show running festivals first(order by: start_date) then upcoming festivals(order by: start_date separately).

For example:

```
festival A: start_date: 15-may  - end_date: 15-june  
festival B: start_date: 01-june - end_date: 20-june
festival C: start_date: 01-oct  - end_date: 30-oct
```

- If today is 14-june then order should be `A B C`
- if today is 16-june then order should be: `B C A`
- and finally if today is 1-Feb then order should be: `A B C`

Thank you in advance for responses.

Comment: Please show us your actual model & controller. Else, it is hard to give a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `start_date` and `end_date` are [`Date`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) objects:

```
# get the festivals from the database
festivals = Festival.all

# define the day of interest
day = Date.today

# partition the festivals into running and upcoming
# based on the day of the year (1-366)
running, upcoming = festivals.partition { |f|
  (f.start_date.yday..f.end_date.yday).include? day.yday
}

# sort each array by day of the year
running.sort_by!{ |f| f.start_date.yday }
upcoming.sort_by!{ |f| f.start_date.yday }
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, you got my point correctly and thank you for useful  answer. I just made a small change before implementation:

running, others = festivals.partition { |f|  (f.started_on.yday..f.stopped_on.yday).include? day.yday}

previous = others.partition { |f| f.started_on.yday < day.yday}.first 
upcoming = others.partition { |f| f.started_on.yday < day.yday}.second

running.sort_by!{ |f| f.start_date.yday }
previous.sort_by!{ |f| f.start_date.yday }
upcoming.sort_by!{ |f| f.start_date.yday }

and finally order is running + upcoming + previous

Comment: I just realized that `yday` doesn't work for leap years. You could use something like `date.month * 31 + date.day` for the comparison instead.