# Sorting data by day and month (ignoring year) python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, datetime

I found many questions similar to mine, but none of them answer it exactly ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326305/array-sort-by-date-and-month-only-ignore-year) comes closest, but it focusses on ruby).

I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2014-10-03', '2015-10-02', freq='1D'), 'Variable': np.random.randn(365)})
df.head()

Out[272]: 
        Date  Variable
0 2014-10-03  0.637167
1 2014-10-04  0.562135
2 2014-10-05 -1.069769
3 2014-10-06  0.556997
4 2014-10-07  0.253468
```

I want to sort the data from January 1st to December 31st, ignoring the year component of the `Date` column. The background is that I want to track changes in `Variable` over the year, but my period starts and ends in October.

I thought of creating a seperate column for month and year and then sorting by those. But I am unsure how to do this in a "correct" and concise way.

Expected output:

```
  Date   Variable
0 01-01  0.637167  # (Placeholder-values)
1 01-02  0.562135
2 01-03 -1.069769
3 01-04  0.556997
4 01-05  0.253468
```

Answer (score 2):

On way from `argsort`

```
yourdf=df.loc[df.Date.dt.strftime('%m%d').astype(int).argsort()]
```

Comment: The utilities in `Date.dt...` were basically what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create the `day` and `month` columns by simply doing the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=pd.date_range('2014-10-03', '2015-10-02', freq='1D'), columns=['date'])
df['day'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.day)
df['month'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
```

You could make it even more compact. But quick analysis, you can use the above.